# Writing a function that returns different combinations of letters

Tags: javascript

I was going through some challenges and I need some help to solve this one . I should write function `permutations(string)` that returns an array of all permutations  of the given string .

```
   permutations('a'); // ['a']
   permutations('ab'); // ['ab', 'ba']
   permutations('aabb'); // ['aabb', 'abab', 'abba', 'baab', 'baba', 'bbaa']
```

Comment: do you have some code which does not work?

Comment: I have been working on solving it for several days but none of my codes seemed to do it right .I was thinking to make an array for example 'abc' -->[['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']] and to loop through this array to get the different possibilities and skip the repeated letters , but i can't write the  exact code , thought of using loop + recursion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let permutation = str => {
    let array = [...str];
    let resultado = [];
    for(let i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
        let temp = array.filter((q,c,y)=> c != i);
        for(x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
        {
          let temp2 = temp.slice(0);
          temp2.splice(x,0,array[i]);
          resultado.push(temp2);
        }
    }
    return [...new Set(resultado.map(item => item.join('')))]
}

console.log(permutation('abbb'));
```

That is the long form. It would have to work more than reduce the size of the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I really appreciate your help <33 .